# How to print a JSON object array in Handlebars (client side), that is sent from Node JS server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I have a JSON object in Node JS server:

```javascript
var test = [{
    name: 'name',
    age: 10
}, {
    name: 'name2',
    age: 20
}];
```

I send the object to the client side (Handlebars) by:

```javascript
res.render('/path/myHbs', {
    test:test
});
```

Now in my Handlebars, using jQuery, how to print (in console) all these elements of test? Like…

```javascript
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.jQuery) {
        //console.log(elements of test object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var test = [{
    name: 'name',
    age: 10
}, {
    name: 'name2',
    age: 20
}];

test = JSON.stringify(test) //just stringify the data before sending

res.render('/path/myHbs', {
    test:test
});

//then parse it in the client side
var data = JSON.parse({{test}})

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(test, function(key, value){
    console.log("Name: " + value.name);
    console.log("Age: " + value.age);
});
```

By using [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), it iterates through each item of the object. Did this answer your question?

Comment: It says test is not defined